# Is it possible to deal with multiple states of a Doctrine Entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony 3 project, using Doctrine ORM I'm trying to use multiple states of an entity.

When importing an XML file over a database (that already comes from previous version of this XML file), I'm in a situation where I would need to have two states of an entity side by side for comparison :

- a DB-state version of the entity
- an already-merged but not yet persisted version of the entity

Something like this :

```
$DB_state_entity;
$not_persisted_entity;

if( $DB_state_entity->isSomething() && $not_persisted_entity->isSomethingElse() ){
    // Do something
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that sort of thing with Doctrine ?

Multiple EntityManagers seem to not be designed for this.

**EDIT:**

After reading @Honza Rydrych answer, I achived my goal by requesting needed properties in DB via EntityManager::createNativeQuery.

A can compare merged values with DB values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the way of accessing an entity states as you described above is not possible.

But I'm missing the point why would you do it that way? You can import the data from the XML file to temp object, make comparison, update the original entity and persist it. The app will have an entity and and temp object in memmory, but you scenario would have two "independent" objects in memory too.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I want to do it that way because there are properties in my entities incuding ID, that are not part of the XML, and I cannot retrieve these informations from raw XML. I'm using JMS Serializer and Doctrine EntityManager::merge() to recompute those informations.

But thank you anyway. I will consider changing my approach.